# SQL Server - Column Name as Variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert, sql-server-2012

I'm just wondering if this is possible, I am trying to update/insert into columns however I would like to be able to select the column name into a variable and do it like so:

```
DECLARE @Col
SET @Col = (SELECT TOP 1 somecolumnname FROM mytable)

INSERT INTO someothertable
(ID, @Col) --This is the part I'm querying
SELECT 
ID, 
SomeData
FROM yetanothertable
```

Comment: Make the whole query dynamic sql

Comment: You can't do that. What you can is to do what @mmhasannn said, make it all dynamic sql.

Comment: This is usually a sign that there's something wrong with the data model - there shouldn't be multiple columns containing the same "type" of data, such that it makes sense to try to parametrize which column you're using (nor multiple tables containing the same types of data)

Comment: I am aware the data model is awful but there's little I can do about that :(

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Col as Varchar(100)
SET @Col = (SELECT TOP 1 somecolumnname FROM mytable)

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(500)
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO someothertable'
SET @SQL = @SQL + '(ID,' + @Col + ')'
SET @SQL= @SQL + ' SELECT ID, SomeData FROM yetanothertable'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this?

```
DECLARE @Col varchar(100), @SQL varchar(1000)
SET @Col = (SELECT TOP 1 somecolumnname FROM mytable)

set @SQL='
INSERT INTO someothertable
(ID, '+@Col+')
SELECT 
ID, 
SomeData
FROM yetanothertable'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Because I've been given lots and lots of awful data I need to report from, I think this database was designed by some sort of half wit.